# Wordpress permalink is not working when set to postname

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have problem with my WordPress permalink. I'm running a WAMP server. I tried to change the permalink to postname:  `"/%postname%/"`.

[image: Permalink setting.]

When I test one of my pages I get an 404 Not Found.

[image: When I click on the post title.]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does it work if you use `Plain` permalinks? Did you set up your `.htaccess` properly?

Comment: yes .. Plain is working properly.. and i dont know how to set up .htaccess

Comment: I've added an official answer to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your .htaccess doesn't exists or better said the mod_rewrite isn't working.

My guess though, since you are using wamp, is that the .htaccess was created by wordpress. Just check if the file exists otherwise create it.

Comment: If the answer helped you, it would be nice if you could mark the answer as correct ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [appropriate documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess). In short, you should put a file named `.htaccess` in your root directory and have the following in the file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```